# How to make black and white flash.media.Video?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video

I'm playing around with the flash Video cam and I'm a real puppy-dog-level newbie with Actionscript, flash and the video stuff.

How do I make the video showing in black and white? I would like to say make a "black and White" feature of the video.

Do I have to mess with filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you'll need a [ColorMatrixFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) to do that.

Check out this example: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/27/converting-an-image-to-black-and-white-using-the-colormatrixfilter/